# Get all variadic template types from a struct which is a type parameter in function template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Here is a minimal example:

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct Pack {};

template<typename ...TemplateTemplateTypes>
bool AllConstructible()
{
    return (std::is_constructible_v
            </*do something to archive all types in every TemplateTemplateType*/> 
            and ... and true);
}

struct Empty{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << AllConstructible<Pack<int, const int&>, Pack<Empty>>();
}
```

The function `AllConstructible` will return true iif all `is_constructible_v<Pack's Types>` hold true.

It is easy to achieve all types inside the definition of `Pack`(just use `Types...`) , but how to do it outside?

Comment: Why `return (std::is_constructible_v<TemplateTemplateTypes> and ... and true);` won't work?

Comment: @VTT it can compile, but the result is not true because it will just judge whether `Pack` can be consturcted instead of its template types:  `std::cout << std::boolalpha << AllConstructible<Pack<int, Empty>, Pack<Empty>>();` will also return true

Comment: So you want to check that `int`, `const int &` and `Empty` are constructible?

Comment: No. the signature of `is_constructibble` is `template< class T, class... Args >
struct is_constructible;` I want to check int is constructible from `const int&`, `Empty` is constructible from empty argument and `int` shouldn't not be constructible from `Empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intrude a helper template that ill unpack parameters:

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct Helper;

template<typename ...Types>
struct Helper<Pack<Types...>>
{
    static constexpr bool value{std::is_constructible_v<Types...>};
};

template<typename ...TemplateTemplateTypes>
bool AllConstructible()
{
    return (Helper<TemplateTemplateTypes>::value and ... and true);
}
```